# Order of operations - cross product and simple multiplication

Tags: cross-product

I'm just wondering which takes precedence or if it really matters. It would matter wouldn't it?

For example, this is written in my textbook:

[Equation for magnetic field of a point charge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Ayi.png)

so the [qv X r] in the numerator is the question I have in mind.

Here's my algebraic proof:

q = q;
v = [a, b, c];
r = [d, e, f];

so if we do the cross product first we get:

(bf - ec)i + (cd - af)j +(ae - bd)k

and then distributing the scalar, it would be:

(bfq - ecq)i + (cdq - afq)j +(aeq - bdq)k

In contrast, if we do multiplication first, qv is now [aq, bq, cq]. If we cross product those two, we get the same thing.

(bfq - ecq)i + (cdq - afq)j +(aeq - bbq)k

Algebraically, it doesn't seem to matter. Are there cases where it will matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that [one of the algebraic properties of cross products is that they're compatible with scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties) so that for any scalar $c \in \mathbb R$ and for any vectors $\vec u, \vec v \in \mathbb R^3$, we have that:
$$
c\vec u \times \vec v = c(\vec u \times \vec v) = \vec u \times c \vec v
$$